# Custom Docker image on Git Lab Job cannot connect to localhost

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've created a very simple custom Docker image:

```
FROM postgis/postgis:16-3.4-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
ENV POSTGRES_DB=lopost_test_db
ENV PGDATA=/data/postgres
ENV POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

Now I'm trying to run the following gitlab job

```
test:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/ci_test
  stage: test
  environment:
    name: Production
  script:
    - psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

When the job runs unfortunately I get the following output:

```
$ psql -h localhost -U postgres
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I am able to run the same setup on my local environment and it works perfectly fine. I am on Windows/WSL, I tried to look if host resolution works differently but I couldn't find anything that helped with the issue.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What exactly do you do locally? I suspect that you start the container (`docker run ... --detach`) and then `docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash` (or something along the line). What the pipeline does is more akin to `docker run ... --entrypoint "/bin/bash -c ..." ... ` (i.e. the pipeline overrides the entrypoint). Thus, the postgres service within the container is never started.

Comment: I see, so basically I will have to start the database manually when inside the container

Comment: When you run a container in GitLab CI, the job should only do the things defined in your job script. You don't do any commands to start the postgres server, so the server is understandably not started.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't started the database server, so that's why you cannot connect.

The typical way to do this is to use `services:` in GitLab. This has the benefit that your job will wait for the service to be available before the job script starts.

```yaml
myjob:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/ci_test
  services:
    - name: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/ci_test
      alias: postgres
  script:
    - psql -h postgres -U postgres
```

Alternatively, you can start the server in the script:

```yaml
myjob:
  # ...
  script:
    - 'docker-entrypoint.sh postgres &'  # start the server
    - sleep 60  # wait for it to start... this could be improved
    - psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, gitlab indeed override the entrypoint. Thanks to @turing85's comment, I was able to start the database in the container and run integration tests.

In the Dockerfile: circumventing that postgres doesn't allow starting a database as root, and that we can't switch to another user in the container, here's a workaround, since is an ephemeral testing database, hacking our way to start postgres is fine:

```
# creating and starting database
RUN chown postgres  # gives user postgres ownership of the home directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/postgres  # creates the data store
RUN chown -R postgres /data # gives user postgres ownership of the /data directory
RUN su postgres -c "initdb" # run initdb as postgres
RUN chmod 0700 /data/postgres # change permissions for the folder
```

Then in the gitlab-ci file

```
- su postgres -c "pg_ctl -D /data/postgres -l logfile start"
```

The postgres server starts successfully